# Can't add line breaks to google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet with the text I wish to use in an email.
The sheet has 50 rows and 3 columns of text, formatted as required.
I have written code that will grab the sheet contents, but it doesn't have line feeds where I want them (funnily enough, at the end of the lines)
It returns the sheet data as one lump of text.

I have tried `\n` and `char(10)`

```
var EmailLines = sSheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows).getValues();
```

I thought it might be a simple add the LF at the end of each line but the array doesn't recognise line feeds ?

Comment: Can you provide more details? What do the spreadsheet cell values look like? What exactly did you try to do when you say "the array doesn't recognize line feeds"? Even better, provide a small, reproducible example of the problem you're having. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I can add `+ '\r\n'` to the end of each line in an email and it works fine.

Comment: If you don't edit your question to provide more context, it's hard to provide you any specific guidance. As said before, what would help is an example of the data your pulling from the sheet. And what sort of manipulations you're attempting after calling `getValues()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`var text=EmailLines.join('\r\n');`