# How To Add Break Line From App Script To Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to add a break line between array to Google Sheet. I tried `<br>` and `&#10;` but it doesn't work and shows those text between the array in Google Sheet instead. Is there a way to do it? Your response would be very appreciated.

Here's my .gs code:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = ws.getRange(5, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 9).getValues();
  var codeList = data.map(function(r){return r[0].toString(); });
  var thingsList = data.map(function(r){return r[8]; });
  var position = codeList.indexOf(formObject.codeInput);

  var array = [thingsList[position], formObject.things].join('<br>').toString();
  if (position > -1) {
    position += 5;
    ws.getRange(position,9).setValue(array);
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried  `'\r\n'`  might need to escape them.

Comment: Wow nice! `\n` work as expected! Thank you @Cooper!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't add line breaks to google script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58019509/cant-add-line-breaks-to-google-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what your looking for:

```
function writem() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].join('\r\n'));
}
```

[image]